# How to poulate the JSON data and display in the dropdown

Tags: json, cordova, dropdown

I am creating an hybrid mobile application using cordova. Here i am having a drop down list. The data inside the drop down list needs to be populated from the JSON data which externally came from the URL. I am retrieving the JSON data successfully but coming to the attaching that JSON data to the drop down i was failed.Can any one tell me how to attach the JSON data to the dropdown.Can any one tell me how to attach the JSON data to the dropdown

This is my code in Java script

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "http://sample/sl/itemcategories.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data, // pass it in here
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    $('#item_category').append('<option value="'+data[i].CategoryId+'">'+data[i].CategoryName+'</option>');
                }
            }
      });
    });
```

This is my HTML

```
<div class="input-field col s10">
    <div >
        <select id="item_category">


        </select>
    </div>
    <label>Select category</label>
</div>
```

Comment: On page loading time

Answer (score 0):

Do it when your [DOM has finished loading](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-callback) otherwise item_category might be not created yet:

```
// wait for document to be ready
$(function() 
{
      $.ajax({
            url: "http://sample/sl/itemcategories.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data, // pass it in here
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    $('#item_category').append('<option value="'+data[i].CategoryId+'">'+data[i].CategoryName+'</option>');
                }
            }
      });
 });
```